# Unable to start SQL Node in Mysql-cluster

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, mysql-cluster

mysqld: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file

I'm trying to configure MySQL-Cluster with the Auto-Installer. When I deploy and start the cluster I get the following message when starting the sql nodes

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgvI4.png)

So I checked the permissions of the files. ls -l looks like this:

```
   drwxrwxr-x 3 mysql ubuntu 4096 Sep 10 03:00 1 
   drwxrwxr-x 3 mysql ubuntu 4096 Sep 10 03:00 2
   drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql ubuntu 4096 Sep 10 03:30 49
   drwxrwxr-x 5 mysql ubuntu 4096 Sep 10 03:03 53
```

And inside the 53 folder:

```
   -rw-rw-r-- 1 mysql ubuntu  214 Sep 10 03:25 my.cnf
   drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql ubuntu 4096 Sep 10 03:00 mysql
   drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql ubuntu 4096 Sep 10 03:00 test
   drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql ubuntu 4096 Sep 10 03:00 tmp
```

I have tried to run the command manually and I get the following message:

```
   ubuntu@mysql-cluster-1:~/MySQL_Cluster/53$ !41
   /usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/home/ubuntu/MySQL_Cluster/53/my.cnf
   mysqld: [ERROR] Could not open required defaults file: /home/ubuntu/MySQL_Cluster/53/my.cnf
   mysqld: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

The file my.cnf contains this configuration:

```
   #
   # Configuration file for test1
   # Generated by mcc
   #
   [mysqld]
   log-error=mysqld.53.err
   datadir="/home/ubuntu/MySQL_Cluster/53/data"
   tmpdir="/home/ubuntu/MySQL_Cluster/53/tmp"
   basedir="/usr/"
   port=3306
   ndbcluster=on
   ndb-nodeid=53
   ndb-connectstring=10.142.0.2:1186,
   socket="/home/ubuntu/MySQL_Cluster/53/mysql.socket"
   ndb-wait-setup=120
   ndb-batch-size=32768
   ndb-blob-read-batch-bytes=65536
   ndb-blob-write-batch-bytes=65536
   ndb-deferred-constraints=0
   ndb-log-apply-status=0
   ndb-log-empty-epochs=0
   ndb-log-empty-update=0
   ndb-log-exclusive-reads=0
```

Edit 1: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and MySQL Cluster 7.6.7 installed with the .deb files

Comment: It looks like is a bug in the .deb files. If you are getting this error try the Generic Linux version (tarball).